# AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import *


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.title('test')
        self.geometry('300x350')
        self.setup_ui()
        self.ctrl()
        self.tmp = True

    def ctrl(self):
        if self.tmp == True:
            showwarning(title='warning',message='warning')

    def setup_ui(self):
        menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        menuFile = tk.Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=menuFile)
        menuFile.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.ctrl())
        self.configure(menu=menubar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

When i run this code:

i got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/calc/test.py", line 29, in <module>
    app = Application()
  File "E:/calc/test.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.setup_ui()
  File "E:/calc/test.py", line 24, in setup_ui
    menuFile.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.ctrl())
  File "E:/calc/test.py", line 17, in ctrl
    if self.tmp == True:
  File "D:\py3.7\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2101, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'tmp'
```

i think the problem is caused `self.tmp = True` and the tkinter think it's a order, but i jusy want to let it as a variable.

i don't know why and how fix the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command=self.ctrl()` *immediately* calls `self.ctrl()` and assigns the result to `command`.

You also have the problem that in `__init__` you call `self.ctrl` before assigning a default value to `self.tmp`

Comment: So how can i fix the problem ?

Comment: "The problem is that you do X before Y". The solution, therefore, is to do Y before X. `self.tmp` has to exist before the code that uses it.

Comment: Two fixes: remove the `self.ctrl()` call in `__init__`, and remove the `()` in `command=self.ctrl`.